# Can a part of an index be used in a query featuring an AND in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Assume I have a two-field index on fields `foo`, `bar`.
When querying `SELECT id FROM table WHERE foo = 1 AND baz = 3`, is the index on `foo` and `bar` being used in the process at all or should I separate the queries instead?

Comment: check your execution plan

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN` before your query to check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way of checking query plan

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM table WHERE foo = 1 AND baz = 3
```

from this plan you can see the details of the index used by the query

Answer (score 1):

with this query

```
   SELECT id 
  FROM table
  WHERE foo = 1
  AND baz = 3,
```

and

```
   SELECT id 
  FROM table
  WHERE foo = 1
```

the index  on  (foo,bar) is used

with this is not used  (the missing column foo .. obscure the index  access for baz)

```
  SELECT id 
  FROM table
  AND baz = 3,
```